# Javascript class method responds "not a function"

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I'm working through an example on tree data structures and have his an impasse.

```
class BinaryNode {
    constructor(n){
    // a node has data, left, and right pointers
    // left and right are intialized as null
      return {data: n, left: null, right: null}     
    }
}

class BinaryTree {
    constructor(){
        // when a new Tree is made, it has a root property
        return {root: null }
    }
  
    insert(data){
        // add a new Node to the tree, with data as the Node's data
        let node = BinaryNode(data)
        return BinaryNode(data)
    }
```

The mocha test:

```
it('should place the first node as the root', ()=>{
    let tree = new BinaryTree();
    tree.insert(5);
    expect(tree.root.data).to.equal(5);
    expect(tree.root.left).to.equal(null);
    expect(tree.root.right).to.equal(null);
});
```

The third test fails with:

```
TypeError: tree.insert is not a function
```

I've been futzing with this for at least 2 hours, and I can't figure out what's wrong.
The codepen is https://codepen.io/kingram/pen/ExgbMVJ

I'd like to figure out why this isn't working.

*UPDATE*
After the comments from @connexo, I realized I was completely in the idiot zone regarding the constructor.

Comment: Constructors shouldn't return anything.

Comment: Your constructor returns `{ root: null }`, nothing more, as per your instruction. If anything, your constructor needs to return `this` (which it would do unless your requested it to do otherwise). `this` is also where you need to attach your properties. Also your method is not a *class method*  (which usually refers to static methods), it's a simple instance method.

Comment: you are returning `BinaryNode` instance which does not have `insert` method

Comment: @Chandan No, that is not at all the problem here. The problem has already been fully explained in the comments.

Comment: @connexo yes but i was just telling other problem

Comment: There is no other problem. Whatever you feel you've spotted, doesn't exist.

Comment: Yeah, I totally misunderstood the requirements for a passing test.
Once I corrected my constructor, I got a different error, that I can see how to fix.
Thanks.

Comment: @connexo sorry my mistake i was checking `BinaryTree` insert method which returns `BinaryNode` instance which is never being used

Answer (score 1):

A `constructor` should not `return` anything, and it must be called with `new`. Instead, create properties on `this`:

```
class BinaryNode {
    constructor(n) {
        // a node has data, left, and right pointers
        this.data = n;
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
    }
}

class BinaryTree {
    constructor(){
        this.root = null;
    }
  
    insert(data){
        // add a new Node to the tree, with data as the Node's data
        let node = new BinaryNode(data)
        … // you probably want to alter `this.root`
    }

    …
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I did figure that out  from the comments by @connexo.